# How to set routes in asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have asp.net core application. In my application the default route is set to `Home/Index/id`

I have one more controller name `Document`

```
 public class DocumentController : Controller
 {
        public IActionResult Index(int? id)
        {          
           // id may be null. Do something with id here 
            return View();          
        }

        public IActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
          return View();
        }
 }
```

in startp.cs i have setup my route as below

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "document",
                    template: "Document/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Document", action = "Index" });

            });
```

i can browse the document view as `http://localhost:40004/Document` or `http://localhost:40004/Document?id=1234`

however i want the following routes to be valid
 `http://localhost:40004/Document/1234`
 `http://localhost:40004/Document?id=1234`
 `http://localhost:40004/Document/Details/1234`
 `http://localhost:40004/Document/Details?id=1234`

What should be my route configuration in startup.cs?

Comment: Your question update is different from your original post! You should not be doing that after someone posts an answer for your first post

Comment: You want to return details view for all the requests ?

Comment: no. they are two different routes . `http://localhost:40004/Document/1234` should return `Index` view and `http://localhost:40004/Document/Details/1234` should return `Detail` view

Comment: see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : As per the question edit

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "document",
        template: "Document/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Document", action = "Index" });
});
```

This route definition will work for all the route patterns you have

You do not need a specific route definition for the details url as it matches with the default convention(taken care by the default route definition). So it will work fine

Comment: `Document/1234` and `Document/Details/4444` both routes should work